# Java Spring Mongo Sort Ignore Case issue

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I am using Spring-Data-mongodb performing all kind of requests to MongoDB.

When trying to perform paging & sort with ignore case I get an exception,

Here's my code:

```
Sort.Order order = new Sort.Order(ascending? Sort.Direction.ASC: Sort.Direction.DESC, sortKey).ignoreCase();
    Query query = new Query(filter).with(new PageRequest(page, size, new Sort(order)));
    return mongoTemplate.find(query, clazz,collection);
```

notice the .IgnoreCase() method applied on the Sort.Order Object.

The Query .with Method fails and throws the exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given sort contained an Order for lastName with ignore case! MongoDB does not support sorting ignoreing case currently!
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query.with(Query.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query.with(Query.java:162)

If removing the .IgnoreCase() method, i.e executing the following code:

```
Sort.Order order = new Sort.Order(ascending? Sort.Direction.ASC: Sort.Direction.DESC, sortKey);
Query query = new Query(filter).with(new PageRequest(page, size, new Sort(order)));
return mongoTemplate.find(query, clazz,collection);
```

Everything works fine, except of course I don't get insensitive sorted results.

hence I might get A B C a1 a2, instead of A a1 a2 B C.

Even though the exception mentions that mongoDB doesn't support IgnoreCase sort, I am using mongo 3.4 which in my understanding does support ignoreCase option for pageable sort ([Here's the official JIRA issue regarding insensitive search feature added](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90)), and my spring-data-mongodb package is 1.8.

Comment: what is your spring-data-mongodb version?

Comment: @pvpkiran 1.8.0 as stated in the original post.

Comment: try with newer version

Comment: Tried with 1.9 and it doesn't work.

Other versions (2+) can cause too much chaos and deprecation of old code. I'm not ready yet to update my whole server infrastructure and DB requests with new API.

Comment: You require collation to make use case of insensitive sort/search which is enabled with collation option strength set to 2 when you sort. 1.10 spring version is [compatible](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#new-features.1-10-0) with Mongo 3.4 but I'm not sure why collation option was left out. Collation feature is only available from 2.0 version. You can create a jira [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel) to check if they can back port the code to 1.10.

Comment: So in summary [ignoreCase](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1616) option doesn't work the way you think it should and you will need a way to pass the collation option with your query and 1.10 spring code doesn't provide such option.

Comment: @Veeram thanks.

I evnetually upgraded my project's code to support spring-data-mongodb v2.0.2 which is latest and stable. everything seems to works fine but i still do get the same error produced.. I am using now spring 2.0.2 and mongodb 3.4.

I did set up collation index(through Mongo CLI) with strength 2.
Yet I keep getting the same exception and the same error, i dug inside source code of spring and I found the same code block from spring 1.8 that generates the error.

Comment: public Query with(Sort sort) {

  Assert.notNull(sort, "Sort must not be null!");

  if (sort.isUnsorted()) {
   return this;
  }

  sort.stream().filter(Order::isIgnoreCase).findFirst().ifPresent(it -> {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Given sort contained an Order for %s with ignore case! "
     + "MongoDB does not support sorting ignoring case currently!", it.getProperty()));
  });

  this.sort = this.sort.and(sort);
  return this;
 }

^ Spring 2.0.2 source code of Query.with method throwing an exception just like spring 1.8.0 for insensitive sort query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry if my comments were not clear. You've to send collation with sort query.

Strength primary and secondary both will provide case insensitive sort. Make sure you use the exact collation criteria in your sort query to take advantage of index.

```
Sort.Order order = new Sort.Order(ascending? Sort.Direction.ASC: Sort.Direction.DESC, sortKey);
Query query = new Query(filter).with(new PageRequest(page, size, new Sort(order)));
query.collation(Collation.of("en").strength(Collation.ComparisonLevel.secondary()));
return mongoTemplate.find(query, clazz,collection);
```

Comment: Thanks I came up with the same solution now I see you've posted.

Accept this great answer.