# Java Spring Data Mongodb 1.10 Sort Ignore Case

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

While running a query with sort on a Spring Data mongo repository, the sort is case sensitive. However, I would like to get query results ignoring case.

This issue has already been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093549/java-spring-mongo-sort-ignore-case-issue) and there is a valid answer to set `Collation` on `Query`. Unfortunately, the `Collation` class has only been introduced in Spring Data MongoDb 2, which is not yet supported by SpringBoot parent starter poms, so if possible I would like to avoid the dependency tuning required if the starter pom is not used.

Is there any workaround to get the same result on Spring Data MongoDb 1.10?

Answer (score 0):

To update `spring-data` modules you have to update whole release train. Unfortunatelly AFAIK there is no list of train versions, however `Kay` is based on the Spring Data 2.x. Just add property to your `pom.xml`

```
<spring-data-releasetrain.version>Kay-SR3</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
```

Comment: This approach would require tuning up a lot of things handled by Spring Boot autoconfiguration manually (methods used by Spring Boot autoconfiguration repackaged,  new Data Configuration classes implementing interfaces, but missing abstract method implementation in class extension hierarchy like `HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration`  and causing `AbstractMethodError` during configuration, Spring Data Classes implementing Spring Boot Autoconfig interfaces, but not implementing all the methods). It would probably even be easier to add additional column with uppercased strings to use for sort.