# Case-insensitive sort using Query class in Spring Data Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using this type of sorting, and I want to be case insensitive.

```
            Query query = new Query();
            query.with(new Sort(new Order(Sort.Direction.ASC,"title").ignoreCase()));
            return db.find(query, Video.class);
```

I tried this query but I don't get any results back.

Imports used:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Order;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
```

For example, if I have this type of titles:
"Inception","BlackList","adore","123", "city","desperadoS"

The order should be:
"123","adore","BlackList","city","desperadoS","Inception"

If i use it this way

```
        Query query = new Query();
        query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC,"title"));
        return db.find(query, Video.class);
```

It returns

"123","BlackList","Inception","adore","city","desperadoS"

Spring-data-mongodb version 1.9.2

Comment: You can try using the _collation_ option for case-insensitive sort.

Comment: i saw that, but where to put that in my example? when i try in eclipse there is no that kind of function to use in my example

Comment: Query class has a `collation()`.

Comment: What is the version of spring-data-mongodb?

Comment: 1.9.2.RELEASE this is the version

Comment: `collation()` is not in your version (1.9.2).

Comment: i can't change my version, so any others suggestions?

Comment: An option is to sort in Java code (not Spring Data MongoDB APIs) - get the documents as a collection (like an `ArrayList`, for example) and then sort , maybe using a custom `Comparator`.

Comment: i've tried that also, but it's not returning correct, maybe becouse i have numbers in the titles, i don't know . I've tried to get only the Videos with mongo and sort it in service by using compareToIgnoreCase and it is not returning correct, the titles are mixed

Comment: What comparator did you use?

Comment: Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Video>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(final Video c1, final Video c2) {
    int c;
    c = c1.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(c2.getTitle());
    return c;
   }
  });

Comment: Is this what you want? `[123, adore, BlackList, city, desperadoS, Inception]`. If, so what is your `equals` override doing?

Comment: yes, the result to be first number, then letters case insensitive

Comment: With proper `equals` override method, you will get the correct output.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to use `Collation` with `@Query` annotation to get the expected sorting order of `"123","adore","BlackList","city","desperadoS","Inception"`

**Document**

```
@Document(collection = "video")
@Data
public class Video {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String title;

    public Video(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface VideoRepository extends MongoRepository<Video, String> {

    @Query(collation = "en", value = "{}")
    List<Video> getAllSortedVideos(Sort sort);

}
```

Integration Test class to assert the changes

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = DemoApplication.class, 
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class VideoRepositoryITest {

    @Autowired
    private VideoRepository videoRepository;

    @Test
    void getAllSortedVideos() {
        List<String> expectedSystemNamesInOrder = Arrays.asList("123", "adore", "BlackList",
                                                    "city", "desperadoS", "Inception");
        //breaking the order for fun
        Set<String> expectedSystemNamesSet = new HashSet<>(expectedSystemNamesInOrder);
        //saving the videos of each title
        expectedSystemNamesSet.stream().map(Video::new)
                .forEach(videoRepository::save);
        //fetching sorted Videos by title
        List<Video> videos = videoRepository.getAllSortedVideos(Sort.by(Direction.ASC, "title"));
        //fetching sorted Video tiles to assert
        List<String> titles = videos.stream().map(Video::getTitle).collect(Collectors.toList());
        //asserting the result video title order with the expected order
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
            String actualTitle = titles.get(i);
            String expectedTitle = expectedSystemNamesInOrder.get(i);
            //Test case will fail if the retrieved title order doesn't match with expected order
            Assertions.assertEquals(expectedTitle, actualTitle);
        }
    }

}
```

Using `org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:3.0.4.RELEASE`

Answer (score 0):

Use collation to sort ignoring cases.
Example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48144192/7190923)

You will get an IllegalArgumentException, when use
`new Order(Sort.Direction.ASC,"title").ignoreCase())`

In your case:

```
Query query = new Query().with(Sort.by(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "title")));
query.collation(Collation.of("en").strength(Collation.ComparisonLevel.secondary()));
return mongoTemplate.find(query, Video.class);
```

Comment: Can you show your code with usage of collation?  @JuniorProgrammer123

Comment: i tried to put collation() everywhere and it's not recognizing it

Comment: The full working example for you is in my answer. Worked for spring-boot 2.3.2

Comment: it returns error for Sort.by and Collation.of
my version is probably old and it's not recognizing 
version : 1.9.2

Comment: Do you have null values in titles, when you use sort in list of videos by titles?

Comment: no null values, onlu values with numbers in it, and titels starting with upper or lower case